# __gnu_cxx hash map with keys of type std::pair<std::string, unsigned int>?

Tags: c++, hashtable, hashmap

Since `std::pair<std::string, unsigned int>` is not defined for __gnu_cxx hash map, how do I create a __gnu_cxx hash map with keys of type `std::pair<std::string, unsigned int>` and values of type `std::pair<int, CBTNODE>`? (`CBTNODE` is `typedef` as `typedef int CBTNODE`)

If it's possible, I would really want to substitute `std::pair<std::string, unsigned int>` with a typedef-ed `INDEX` (`typedef std::pair<std::string, unsigned int> INDEX`)

Any help will be much appreciated!

Z.Zen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to compile and print the right answer (1):

```
#include <hash_map>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef int CBTNODE;
typedef std::pair<std::string, unsigned int> INDEX;
typedef std::pair<int, CBTNODE> Element;

struct pairhash{
    size_t operator()(const INDEX &p) const {
        return
          __gnu_cxx::hash<const char*>()(p.first.c_str()) ^
          __gnu_cxx::hash<unsigned int>()(p.second);
    }
};

int main() {
    __gnu_cxx::hash_map<INDEX, Element, pairhash> x;
    INDEX foo("hi", 0);
    Element bar(1, 2);
    x[foo] = bar;
    std::cout << x[foo].first << "\n";
}
```

Which was a bit tedious. The issue is that `__gnu_cxx::hash` doesn't provide a specialization for `pair`, or for that matter for `string` either. I believe it follows the SGI API here: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash.html. So `pairhash` (or something like it) is needed to provide the missing hash function.

I don't blame you for not spotting that, since the compiler error that this caused was a bit, um, non-obvious. And long.

If you can, you're probably better off using `boost::unordered_map`. SGI's `hash_map` is an old API, never adopted into the standard, due to be replaced in C++0x, etc, etc.